# Oracle - Sql query to get the latest record in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table and tried to run the following query to get the latest DEPTID according to the EFFDT which is 
the second row (DAA System Infrastructur 1/13/2017) but I still get all of the records. What I am doing wrong here?

I did looked at similar questions but non had the same problem as I do.

```
select  d.deptid,d.descr,d.effdt
 from SYSADM.PS_DEPT_TBL d
 inner join( select deptid,descr,max(to_date(effdt)) as max_date 
              from SYSADM.PS_DEPT_TBL 
              group by deptid, descr) d1
 on d.deptid = d1.deptid  
 and to_date(effdt) = max_date
where d.deptid ='DAA'
```

This is the table:

```
DEPTID   DESCR                 EFFDT
-------------------------------------------
DAA      Telecommunications        2/18/2013
DAA      System Infrastructure         1/13/2017
DAA      Manager, Telecommunications    1/1/1900
DAA      System Infrastructure & Contrl 7/8/2013
```

Comment: You can invert the order and take the first with a `LIMIT 1`

Comment: `descr` shouldn't be part of the derrived table/inline view nor part of the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
group by deptid, descr
```

Your subquery includes `descr` in the projection and grouping, so it will calculate the maximum effective date for each combination of those two columns. So it returns four rows with four different values of `max_date`, and that's why your final result is what it is.

The solution is simple:

```
select  d.deptid,d.descr,d.effdt
 from SYSADM.PS_DEPT_TBL d
 inner join( select deptid,max(to_date(effdt)) as max_date 
              from SYSADM.PS_DEPT_TBL 
              group by deptid) d1
 on d.deptid = d1.deptid  
 and to_date(effdt) = max_date
where d.deptid ='DAA'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT deptid, descr, effdt
    FROM SYSADM.PS_DEPT_TBL
    WHERE deptid = 'DAA'
    ORDER BY effdt DESC
) resultSet
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Why the wacky non-Oracle syntax?

Comment: Because I don't see Oracle since ages... what are my mistakes?

Comment: Literals use single quotes not double-quotes. Identifiers don't use backticks.